# Android Db code hang my app for 10 secods , black screens come that show hangs after this activty ok

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my code for mystartup `Acitivty`. when launched, i put the db code where i display message db loading... etc . it works fine but the problems is in the following code which cause black screen for 5 to 10 seconds. After that everything ok. So i don't want to be in this state .

// oncreate event of mystartup activty here is the code

```
    SharedPreferences prefre=this.getSharedPreferences("firstt",this.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean firsttimes=prefre.getBoolean("firstt", true);

    if(firsttimes)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editere=prefre.edit();
        editere.putBoolean("firstt", false);
        editere.commit();

        MyAlterts alterts=new MyAlterts();
        alterts.ShowMsgWithOk(this,"db loaded ..... wait");

        //calling db functions first run so that optmize next time
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.openreadabledb();

        //db code here also
        return;
    }
```

Comment: on bluestack amulator it workfine but on device it hangs the acitvty for few seconds the task code databaseaccess is openorcreate db firsttime so that's why from sdcard it perform action on code it takes time . so if this code call anywhere in the application first time it hangs the operations that's why i call after first run

Comment: change ` editere.commit();` to `editere.apply();` if the problem exists, it is related to **DatabaseAccess**

Comment: yes its related to databaseaccess code, i know the code is responsible for hangs for few seconds bcz database size large so how to tackle this . i just put it on background work but with proper dialogue showing db loading how to do that

Comment: you should use another thread/service. just do that and you'll be ok. because now you use your UI thread that cause your screen to go nuts.

Answer (score 0):

All the db operations have to be performed in background thread else the app will be stuck showing black screen. So you will have to move the db operation to an asynctask.

Comment: You can show the dialog from the onPreExecute method in the asynctask. Do the db operations from doInBackground method and after the db operation is complete, you can dismiss the dialog from onPostExecute method in the asynctask.

Comment: i don't recommend AsyncTask because it is for short jobs. service is more suitable

Comment: Service will make it more heavy. For db operations asynctask is the most preferable way.

Comment: Please refer this link http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

Comment: Please up vote the answer if you have found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: @fightingCoder, where did you find out that asynctask is more preferable wayfor DB operation? please give me some reference or something to read. thanks

Comment: We had followed this pattern for our project and we could get good working flow with this.

Answer (score 0):

Database requests should be ran on a seperate background thread. This is a simple way you can do it using AsyncTask.

public class request extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Stirng result="";

        //Make your Database Requests here, you can store the result in the //string result which is what this method will return

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        //After doInBackground method has finished executing, the result //will be stored in the perimeter variable above 'result'
        //process your result here

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //you can implement an action here e.g a progress dialog to run //when this class is executed, call dialog.dismiss() in onPostExecute
        //and dialog will be dismissed after the result has been received //ni onPostExecute


    }


}
```

Finally go ahead and execute this method in your onCreate().

```
request req = new request();
req.execute();
```

Comment: You can give an upvote so that someone else can identify the working solution.